# Linux code editor with bookmark toggling via mouse?

Tags: linux, text-editor, mouse, editor

On Windows, Notepad++ is my favorite editor because I use the mouse to toggle bookmarks by clicking the line number.

Is there a code editor that does that on Linux? Atom and Sublime only appear to support a keyboard shortcut, and SciTE doesn't even do that.

I'm using Xubuntu 16.04 on a 32-bit Dell Latitude D630.

Comment: I use Geany, and can get a marker to show up next to a line by cliking in the space between line number adn actual editor window.  However, I can't figure out what those marks are used for....

Comment: @ivanivan You can mark the lines you're working on and switch between them using Ctrl+, and Ctrl+. Notepad++ uses F2 and Shift+F2 for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to [get Notepad++ working in Wine.](https://superuser.com/a/1191605/103551)

[Geany](https://www.geany.org/) also supports simple mouse-based bookmarking, but requires two keys to cycle through them.

Answer (score 0):

[Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) could be a good choice for you to try:

- it is available for most platforms
- Right Click, Bookmarks, Toggle Bookmark
- Right Click in margin, Add Bookmark
- Ctrl-B to toogle Bookmark
- Support for multiple programming languages
- Full IDE for C/C++/Fortran
- C/H file swap
- Go To Declaration/Implementation
- Find callers, instances, etc.
- Free, Gratis & Open Source.
- Plug-ins
- Custom Syntax Highlighting
- Multiple Compilers Supported

Comment: I prefer a single left click to toggle, single key to switch focus, and most recent version via Synaptic.

Answer (score 0):

[CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com) editor does that on mouse click. Click on gutter, lefter than line numbers, it toggles bookmark for that line.

It is free, runs good on Linux.